# Why did Ash became a child back in Sun Moon Series?

Tags: pokemon

I was watching Pokemon Sun Moon and I think its a continuation because he knows about Pokemon from other regions.

But the question is that why did he became a small kid, from a young guy, who challenged Alain in Kalos League Finals?

He nearly won the match so why did he need to go to Pokemon School?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ash Ketchum has, and will always be, 10 years of age. Sun and Moon has only changed the art style and focus of the anime. Whilst Pokemon of old had some comedy in it, Sun and Moon has made it a priority.

source for age: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash_Ketchum

Comment: Contrast that with Ben 10 omniverse. It is supposed to happen After Alien Force, but he is surely not any more mature.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't noticed, Ash is always 10 no matter what series it is. He never ages. Physically, he is the same 10-year old boy from Kanto that we see in the very first episode of Pokemon.