# Why are Ash/Satoshi's achievements not mentioned in newer seasons?

Tags: pokemon

Ash/Satoshi is the Alola region's Champion, so in the episode where he went back to Alola, I expected that someone would refer to him as the Alolan Champion, but nobody did. In another recent episode, Ash went back to the Unova region to fight Iris, and it was revealed there that Iris is now the Unova region's Champion, but Ash never tells her that he is also now a Champion.

Why isn't Ash's Pokémon League win ever acknowledged?

Comment: Somewhat related? [Why did Ash need to go back to Pokemon School?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/38724/20275). The question is different, but along the same lines

Comment: ya it is reasonable answer @Wondercricket